# Index of intersection of subgroups

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group with subgroups $H$ and $K$ with index $r=[G:H]$ and $s=[G:K]$. Show that: $[G:H\cap K]\leq rs$

I know it works with Lagrange, but I don't know exactly how.

Comment: What has this to do with `linear-algebra`?

Comment: Our teacher asked us in the linear algebra class to think about that over the weekend. I guess its more a lookout for the algebra class next year